# Kendo UI Flatcolorpicker does not render correctly in a Kendo UI Window

Tags: kendo-ui, color-picker, kendo-mvvm

KendoUI version 2013.3.1119
Using Kendo MVVM

I have a color selector that I have build that uses a flat color picker and a color picker using a palette. They both function correctly but the layout of the flat color picker is off where the track for the slider does not render to the appropriate width.

[image]

If the flatcolorpicker is loaded directly in a page and not in a kendo window it renders correctly.

There are not any special settings I am applying.

```
<div id="flatColorPicker"
     data-role="flatcolorpicker"
     data-bind="value: colorPaletteValue, enabled: enableColorSelection, events: { change: colorPaletteChange }">
</div>
```

**What I have tried**

- Removed all other html around it, same result within the window.
- Tried to forcefully set the size of the track.
- Used Chrome dev tools to manipulate the CSS.
- Stepped through the Kendo UI javascript to see where it renders initially.

**What worked, but not a resolution**

Manually re-size the window using the mouse after initial load, it then corrects itself.

[image]

Has anyone else experienced this or has any other ideas to try?

**KendoUI Window settings:**

```
{
title: "Set Color",
resizable: false,
draggable: false,
width: 550,
height: 300,
actions: ["Close"]
}
```

Comment: Hey, just wondering how you managed to get the palette and picker into the same dialog? I've been trying to do something similar but can't seem to get it working. I was even trying to get them displaying without a dialog like so https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/colorpicker/events but that still doesn't work for me. Any tips?

Comment: @seam le roy - I use MVVM pattern so create an HTML file that has your window content with both items. Load this content into a kendo view that you open inside of the window.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for getting back to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran in to the same issue:

[image]

I don't know if this will fix it for you, but I fixed it by making sure the picker's container element was visible before instantiating it. My code used to look like:

```
$picker.kendoFlatColorPicker({
    // config
})
$container.show(); // $container contains the $picker
```

Turns out if I just reverse the order it started working:

```
$container.show(); // $container contains the $picker
$picker.kendoFlatColorPicker({
    // config
})
```

[image]